# Do logic on keypress down of textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I need to do some logic but only from a specific textbox.  Trying to do some search it appears that there is no event for KeyDown or PreviewKeyUp for a textbox but for the entire window.  So in XAML I have this

```
PreviewKeyUp="keyPressLogic"
```

Then have a method that looks like this;

```
   private void keyPressLogic(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Key == Key.Down) && (check focus command ) )
        {
            //My logic
            return;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I cannot figure out the check focus command.  So either I am missing the key check on the textbox or got to find the focus command

thanks

Comment: Try `(sender as TextBox).IsFocused`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the textbox you pressed you should:

```
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
```

and then you can:

```
 private void keyPressLogic(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     if ((e.Key == Key.Down) && (textbox.IsFocused))
     {
         //My logic
         return;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Won't this just check to see if **any** textbox is in focus?  The OP wanted a __Specific__ textbox.

Comment: @Harrison, it will check any textbox that uses this function as the event handler. By the looks of things, that is only one textbox.

Comment: @gunr2171: So I have 2 textboxes and a checkbox.  If textbox A is in focus when I call this, the if statement is true.  If textbox B is in focus when I call this, the if statement is true.  If the Checkbox is in focus I will have an invalid cast run-time error.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Harrison, true, but I think the only way this function is called is on a keypress event, which will give the focus to the control before the function is called. (actually, now that I think about it, this looks like a keyboard press, not a mouse press, so what's up with that?)

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.Controls.TextBox has an event caleed. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_events.aspx) you can find it. 
It will trigger the KeyDown event only for the textbox you add it on.

Here is how you add it into your XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextbox" KeyDown="MyTextbox_KeyDown" />
```

And here is how your event handler should look like

```
private void MyTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
         // Add your logic here
    }
}
```